# field validation using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how do I validate input fields using javascript and display error message for each field aside from the textbox. I wanted to develop a form with name and contact number for example, but whenever I enter correct or incorrect input, it shows error message I created. I couldn't figure out which part I did wrong. Please help me~!

```js
function validateForm()
{
var name = document.getElementById("custname").value
var regex1 = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

if(!name.match(regex1))
    {
    document.getElementById("nameError").innerHTML = "Name must be in the format of a-z or A-Z";
    return false;
    }

var contact = document.getElementById("contact").value
var regex2 = /^\(\d{2}\)\d{10}$/;

else if(!contact1.match(regex3))
    {
    document.getElementById("contactError").innerHTML = "Contact should be in format (CC)NNNNNNNNNN";
    return false;
    }
return true;
}
```

```css
#nameError{
color:red;
}

#contactError{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<form action="myCheck" method="get" onSubmit="return validateForm()">

<div>
<label for="name"><b>Customer Name: </b></label>
<div>
    <input type="text" name="custname" id="custname" style="width:50%" placeholder="Only character a-z or A-Z">
    <span id="nameError"></span>
    <br /> <br />
</div>
</div>
<br />
<div>
    <label for="name"><b>Contact Number: </b></label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="contact" id="contact" style="width:50%" placeholder="Only (CC)NNNNNNNNNN">
        <span id="contactError"></span>
        <br /> <br />
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (name != "/^[a-zA-Z]+$/")` compares to the literal string "/^[a-zA-Z]+$/". What you need is to test using a regular expression, i.e. `if (!/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(name))`.

Comment: I actually edited it already. The form will just check for first box ("name" field), as long as I type correct input, form proceeds. It will not check for the next field ("contact")

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Regex `match` method instead of the `is not equal` operator `!=`.
See here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string matched with `Regex`, you should use `.test()` method.
For example, with your case, you should use:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
if(regex.test(name)) {
    //Doing something if string name not matched with Regex
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this js code

```
function validateForm(){
        var name = document.getElementById("custname").value;
        var contact = document.getElementById("contact").value
            var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
            if(!name.match(letters)&&isNaN(contact))
            {document.getElementById("nameError").innerHTML = "Name must be in the format of a-z or A-Z";document.getElementById("contactError").innerHTML = "Contact should be in format (CC)";
            return false;
            }
else if(!name.match(letters))
                {document.getElementById("nameError").innerHTML = "Name must be in the format of a-z or A-Z";document.getElementById("contactError").innerHTML = "Contact should be in format (CC)";
            return false;
            }
else if(isNaN(contact))
                {
                document.getElementById("contactError").innerHTML = "Contact should be in format (CC)";
                return false;
                }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Hi there, I actually adopt your suggestion, however, after I amend it, the form seems only be testing the first textbox, whenever I enter wrong input into other boxes, as long as the first one is correct, the form continues to submit... Clueless..